# System.Timers.Timer object works even if I pause or stop website in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, timer

I have a System.Timers.Timer object which starts on Global.Application_Start in ASP.net and saves log records in a table, each 5 seconds.
Even if I stop or pause the website in IIS, the object still works?

How can I stop it Or in which method of global fires when I pause or stop IIS, then I can stp it by code?

Comment: take a look at the Following [Stack Post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5580080/1292203